# Is there any dim or black screen option for only secondary monitor?

Tags: gnome

I am using Manjaro Gnome and I have a secondary monitor.

There is an option on settings that dim screen and black screen after a specific time and I want to do this for only 1 monitor.
For example, when I am watching movie on my secondary monitor, I want that my primary screen is blacked after a specific period.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

ArandR is a good gui tool for this.

If you want to use terminal commands, xrandr is the tool for you:

- List names and properties of connected outputs with: `xrandr --current`
- Turn off output: `xrandr --output <display-name> --off`
- Turn output back on with: `xrandr --output <display-name> --auto`

These are just a few basic commands, xrandr has a wealth of different options you could use to get a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.
I will definitely research on this.